# Checking to see if the Textarea field is null. If so then make no comment

Tags: java, html, jsp

I need some help with my code.
I have a text area that should only display when a radio button is selected. Then whatever is typed into the text area should be sent and stored in the database.
The `two radio` button I have are:

[image]

If `No` is selected then the text area appears:

[image]

The code for that is shown below:

```
<h1>Accept or Decline Invitation</h1>
      <%=txt.displayCustomContent( "accept_text","acceptsection" )%>

      <fieldset >
      <label>Will you be attending the <%=formFields.getValue("programName")%> in <%=formFields.getValue("destination")%> <%=formFields.getValue("programDates")%>?</label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
     <input id="yes" type="radio" name="attending" class="show-hide" value="Yes" <%= formFields.getRadioValue("attending","Yes")%>/> Yes, I will attend. I have read the instructions and I will register now.  
      </fielset>
      <fieldset>
      <input id="no" type="radio" name="attending" class="show-hide" value="No" <%= formFields.getRadioValue("attending","No")%>/> No, I will not attend.
      </fieldset>
      <br/>
      <div id="show-me" style="display:none;"> 
      <fieldset>
      <label>If you will not be attending, please provide a brief explanation below (maximum 40 characters).
          <textarea name="declineReason" id="declineReason" cols="25" rows="3" onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form.declineReason,40);" onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.declineReason,40);"><%= formFields.getTextAreaValue("declineReason")%></textarea>
      </label>
      </fieldset>
      </div>

      <%=txt.displayCustomContent( "accept_textbottom","acceptsectionbottom" )%>


      <div id="registration-navigation">
        <input name="" type="submit" value="next &#62;&#62;" class="button"/>
      </div>
```

Now this is where my problem is..
Even when I select `Yes` the text area is sending information back and storing it in the database.

[image]

The code for storing it is shown below:

```
 if(formFields.exists("declineReason"))
    {
        awsl.setLoginComment("Decline reason is: " + formFields.getValue("declineReason"));
    }
```

So my question is how do I change it so that it only send the info to the database if the text area has text in it?
I have tried to check and see if the text area was was NULL in the if statement, but that did not seem to work.

Comment: I think you need to have the same id with different values for both the radio buttons.

Comment: I just tried that. Didn't fix the problem.

Comment: can I see your textCounter method

Comment: function textCounter(field, maxlimit) {

if (field.value.length > maxlimit) // if too long...trim it!
field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);

}

Comment: why dont you write another js method for form submit, where you can check set the field value based on the value of the radio button

Answer (score 2):

To build off of what @Stultuske said, I would recommend still checking for a null state to avoid the chance for a null pointer exception. But as they said, once it is instantiated it will never return null so you'll need to check if it's empty which essentially just checks for the length of the text within the field.

```
if(jTextArea.getText() == null || jTextArea.getText().isEmpty())
{
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't check on the TextArea being null or not. As soon as you instantiate it, it will return false.

Check on:

```
jTextArea.getText().isEmpty()
```

this doesn't check the area itself as component, but the text in your TextArea.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller check if the text length is == 0.